# Error converting data type varchar to float only when i am using the update not on the select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Error converting data type varchar to float only when i am using the update not on the select.
I am converting 1 line at a time pulling in from a flat file

```sql
   ----;--Column24 [Price]
--      select [Price]    = SUBSTRING(LftOvers, LEN(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(LftOvers))+2, LEN(LftOvers))--I want this one
-- ,[LftOvers] = SUBSTRING((LftOvers),1,Len(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',',Reverse(LftOvers)))--Use if I need no , at the end
--from [SportsBook].[dbo].[stg_betsplaced]

 UPDATE       [SportsBook].[dbo].[stg_betsplaced]
SET [Price]    = SUBSTRING(LftOvers, LEN(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(LftOvers))+2, LEN(LftOvers))--I want this one
 ,[LftOvers] = SUBSTRING((LftOvers),1,Len(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',',Reverse(LftOvers)))--Use if I need no , at the end
```

Comment: Give us a [mre], that SQL has little value to use as it stands.

Comment: I start with the select verify it is what I want then comment it out and create the update statement.

Comment: Sample data and desired resulults would be most helpful

Comment: We can't help if we don't know the values in the data that you're working with.  The error is pretty clear.  It will work for you in a SELECT because you can return a VARCHAR in the result set. For whatever reason SQL Server is not able to do an implicit conversion of your VARCHAR value to FLOAT.  Why, we don't know unless we see your data.

Comment: The `SELECT` simply gives you the native type of the expression. The `UPDATE` is going to convert if `Price` and/or `LftOvers` are of type `FLOAT`, so it's not unexpected you'd have the error then. Consider using `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out there was Currency as well at 'N/A' in the column so this is what I came up with.

```
UPDATE [SportsBook].[dbo].[stg_betsplaced]
SET [Price] = CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(LftOvers, LEN(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(LftOvers))+2, LEN(LftOvers))) ='N/A' THEN 0 
                   ELSE (CONVERT(int,(SUBSTRING(LftOvers, LEN(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(LftOvers))+2, LEN(LftOvers)))))
                   END
    ,[LftOvers] = SUBSTRING((LftOvers),1,Len(LftOvers)-CHARINDEX(',',Reverse(LftOvers)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance